# Redirecting to a newly-created entity from a popup

Tags: angular, redirect, jhipster

In my JHipster application, I have a page with a list of entities:

```
/#/entities
```

To add a new entity, a button opens a popup by navigating to the following URL:

```
/#/entities(popup:entity-new)
```

An entity is shown at the following URL:

```
/#/entities/5
```

Currently, when the popup closes after adding a new entity, the list of entities at `/entities` is refreshed, but I would rather navigate directly to the new entity's page.

I have tried the following:

```
console.log(this.router.url);
this.router.navigate([ response.placeId, { outlets: { aux: null } } ]);
```

Which produces the following in the log:

```
/entities(popup:entity-new)
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'XXX'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'XXX'
```

(where XXX is the ID of the newly-added entity, which is correctly retrieved)

What is the correct way to redirect in a situation like this?

Comment: I dont know the version of angular you're using, but if it's 1.x you can use: $state.go('other-entity-state-detail', {id:newEntityID});